# Store anonymous values in a list and extract each individually

Tags: c#, arrays, list, anonymous, storing-data

I'm trying to store information in a block of anonymous values

```
//holds all info
var jobs = new { newJob, numBytes, requiredTime };
```

then take that information and place it into a list as a single element

```
//puts above info into a list
joblist.Add(Convert.ToString(jobs));
Console.WriteLine(joblist[0]);   //testing purposes
```

now what I would like to do is be able to call joblist and take the value of example numBytes at position 4.

Is this possible? Or could someone help with an alternate way of doing this? Much thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `Convert.ToString()`? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: What do you plan to do with this approach? I think that creating a class for `jobs` with `newJob, numBytes, requiredTime` as properties will make things easier for you

Comment: What do you mean by "remove numBytes"? Do you mean set the property on the object to 0, or actually remove the property? This feels like you are trying to write JavaScript in C#... You might be able to do something with `dynamic` or just use a `Dictionary` instead of an anonymous object. To me it sounds like you are trying to treat C# like a dynamic language, which it isn't.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike I apologize by stating "remove" I can't think of a better word at the moment however what I want to do is take the value of numBytes for example to use somewhere else (not actually remove)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "normal" thing to do in C# would be to create a class to hold the information that you want to store. For example:

```
public class Job
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NumBytes { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequiredTime { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can add these to a list:

```
var jobs = new List<Job>();

var aJob = new Job();
aJob.Name = "Job 1";
aJob.NumBytes = 123;

jobs.add(aJob);
```

Then you can access jobs by its index in the list:

```
var jobNumBytes = jobs[3].NumBytes;
```

---

One thing to note about C#, when you do:

```
new { newJob, numBytes, requiredTime };
```

The compiler, at build time, just creates you a strongly typed class (just like the `Job` class I created above) and generates a random name for it. It infers the property names and types from the variables that you are assigning to it. The created .exe or .dll actually does contain a class definition for this type, you just can't easily get to it from other places in your code. It isn't truly "dynamic". So using that syntax is usually just a lazy way of declaring a class that you just need for a moment. Usually just inside 1 method, then you don't need it any more. Creating a named class is usually what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly and is what @usr was also getting at I believe, thanks to both!

Answer (score 1):

Create a named class. Then you can have a list of objects of that type and manipulate that list in any way you want.

Using classes is best-practice for what you are trying to do. By default you should consider storing structured data in an object model consisting of custom classes. There is another answer here which is proposing to use dynamic - this is valid and has its place, but it is more of a last resort solution. What you want is to play to the strength of C# which are rich classes and static typing. Anonymous types are also statically typed, but as you cannot name the type you cannot declare a statically typed list to hold them. You also can't use them as return types of methods.

Comment: are you saying to make 3 separate lists for newJob, numBytes, and requiredTime? I have that typed out as well but I was wondering if there was a way to hold everything in one list to limit calls and whatnot from other classes. Its harder to explain than it is to have in my head so I apologize, but think of it as a 3 by n array; that's what I would like to achieve

Comment: Do you know about classes in C#? Make yourself familiar with them. An anonymous type is a class without a name, basically. You can also create classes with names. Create one with three properties to hold your data.

Comment: So I create a Job class and have 3 parameters being the ones as stated above and call them as Job.newJob for example.

Comment: Exactly. This is best-practice for what you have. By default you should consider storing structured data in an object model consisting of custom classes. There is another answer here which is proposing to use dynamic - this is valid and has its place, but it is more of a last resort solution. What you want is to play to the strength of C# which are rich classes and static typing. Anonymous types are also statically typed, but as you cannot name the type you cannot declare a statically typed list to hold them. You also can't use them as return types of methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight! Its hard for me to understand things without seeing code but your comments made it easier to understand what was said by @CodingWithSpike

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know exactly what you mean with *"now what I would like to do is be able to call joblist and remove for example numBytes at position 4."*

But I guess you just want to put the objects in a list and query for numBytes and maybe remove some elements.

With dynamics you can handle dynamic objects...

```
var jobs = new List<dynamic>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    string newJob = "Job" + i;
    int numBytes = i;
    TimeSpan requiredTime = new TimeSpan(0,0,i);
    //holds all info
    var job = new { newJob, numBytes, requiredTime };
    jobs.Add(job);
}

jobs.RemoveAll(p => p.numBytes > 50);
```

Instead of this, I agree with the comments below your question and would create a normal class which holds the properties you need and simply put instances of that into a list. Dynamics should be used only in very rare situations, and yours doesn't sound like it is extremely special.